# На чем работает эта галерея?

Tags: jquery

http://papa-carlo.com.ua/cosmopolitan.html кто-нибудь скажет на чем работает эта адская галерея? можно ли где-то скачать этот скрипт?

Comment: http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/

И чего же в ней "адского"?

Answer (score 1):

[Nivo Slider](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/)

upd: ок, под давлением масс убираю выдранный из сайта код.. очень стыдно!))

Comment: Стыдно не код из сайтов "выдирать". Стыдно не думать над тем, что "выдираешь".

Comment: ну может немного